# I'm importing 348k Row of data from Excel to VB.net SQL. And I get this Error: Timeout expired

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel

I get this error:

> system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Code:

```
    Dim ExcelConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\z.fontanilla\Documents\etl.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes""")

    ExcelConnection.Open()

    Dim expr As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
    Dim objCmdSelect As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(expr, ExcelConnection)

    Dim objDR As OleDbDataReader

    Dim SQLconn As New SqlConnection()
    Dim ConnString As String = "Data Source=cyayay\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=reportingDB;Integrated Security=True"
    SQLconn.ConnectionString = ConnString
    SQLconn.Open()


    Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(SQLconn)
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tFalse"

        Try
            objDR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)
            objDR.Close()
            SQLconn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Using
    ExcelConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Maybe your operation is taking just too long... Break it into smaller operations. I mean, send batches of data at a time, commit, then send another batch.

Comment: There you go! Woho! It works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the CommandTimeout property on the objCmdSelect object to 700 (or whatever) value.